# Upvote without getting any reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I have a small question. I answered the following question:
[Equation Alignment With Steps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29387/equation-alignment-with-steps/29390#29390)

You see at the moment I have three upvotes. In my profile I can't see this:
[image]

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You reached the [daily reputation limit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) of 200 plus the additional reputation of the four accepted answers, which makes 260. Additional upvotes don't add reputation.

See also: [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Comment: @Marco: The link Stephan provided states that *"accepted answers and bounty awards are not subject to the daily reputation limit"*. IIRC, also the +2 from accepting an answer to one's own question is immune to the rep limit.

Comment: @Marco: Also, the additional upvotes may not add reputation, but they count with respect to tag badges.

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks